Implicitly creating a struct
In the following query:
select t, 1 from (select 1 as a, 2 as b) t

It produces a column of struct type: {"a": 1, "b": 2} for the column t. Is this the expected behavior, and if so (and I'm almost 100% sure it is), where is that behavior documented in BigQuery or in the SQL standard?
Another example:
select t as x, t.*, 1 as y from (select 1 as a, 2 as b) t



I've been reading the SQL:2023 specification for 30 minutes now without finding anything like this. (Very time-consuming document to read.) Anyway, "following" this question.

@jarlh -- thanks. Where did you find the standard from? Or did you purchase it from the ISO website?

Purchased from ISO.

This is definitely the expected behavior in BigQuery. While the documentation might not show examples exactly like yours, the underlying concept aligns perfectly.  I ran your query using BigQuery's sample structure and got the same results.

SELECT expression

Implicit aliases

Table subqueries


Query 1:
WITH t AS (select 1 as a, 2 as b)
SELECT t, 1 FROM t;

Query 2:
WITH t AS (select 1 as a, 2 as b)
SELECT t as x, t.*, 1 as y FROM t;

The same is observed in a couple of related posts.

SQL script within subquery (Big Query)?

BigQuery - reference results from subquery in another part of the same query


